# Send commands into a Start-Process function call after the initial commands

Tags: powershell

I have the following commands that I need to run in a Command Prompt from PowerShell, in order.

1. `/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\DandISetEnv.bat"`
2. `copype amd64 C:\WinPE_amd64_PS`

I can execute the first command by the following PowerShell command:

```bsh
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\DandISetEnv.bat"'
```

That works fine, but I can't pass the second command into the Start-Process. How do I go about doing that? The `DandISetEnv.bat` file needs to be loaded and the Command Prompt remain open using the `/k` switch.

Is there a switch or command I can put between the first and second command, or redirect the next command into the Command Prompt process that was started up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your intent is to pass multiple commands to `cmd`, you need to separate these commands with *its* statement-chaining operator, `&`:

```
# Define the array of commands to pass to cmd.exe
$cmdCommands = 
  '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\DandISetEnv.bat"',
  'copype amd64 C:\WinPE_amd64_PS'

Start-Process -FilePath cmd -ArgumentList ('/k ' + ($cmdCommands -join ' & '))
```

Note that if you wanted to only execute the latter command if the former succeeds, you should use `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Danijel-JamesW; my pleasure.